# How to disconnect socket when navigating to different screen

Tags: reactjs, sockets, react-native

I am using socket.io-client to fetch the latest data of crypto coin

```
constructor() {
    super();
      this.socket = openSocket('https://coincap.io');
    }
```

then calling it in `componentDidMount`

```
 componentDidMount() {
    this.socket.on('trades', (tradeMsg) => {
          for (let i=0; i< this.updateCoinData.length; i++) {
             console.log("it is being called still")
              if (this.updateCoinData[i]["short"] == tradeMsg.coin ) {
                  this.updateCoinData[i]["price"] = tradeMsg["message"]['msg']['price']
                  //Update the crypto Value state in Redux
                  this.props.updateCrypto(this.updateCoinData);
              }
          }
      })
```

Since the socket is on, it will continue to emit message. Now I thought when I navigate from one screen to another, the socket connection will disconnect and hence I was doing something like this

```
componentWillUnmount() {
 this.socket.disconnect();
}
```

But even though I have navigated to a different page, My socket is continuing to emit signals which means it is still connected.

I am not sure if this is because of **`react-navigation`** but I am using `StackNavigator` here.

This is my `react-navigation` component

```
export const MyScreen = createStackNavigator({
  Home: { 
    screen: CoinCap
  },
  CoinCapCharts: {
     screen: CoinCapCharts
    },
  CurrencySelection: {
    screen: CurrencySelection
  },
  CoinChart: {
    screen: CoinChart
  },
  News: {
    screen: News
  }

},{
    initialRouteName: 'Home',
    headerMode: 'none'
});
```

**Question:** How can I close the socket when user navigate from one screen to another? and turn it back on when the user navigates to the same give screen?

Comment: do `socket.close()` you might want to check this out https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client/blob/master/docs/API.md

Answer (score 4):

## Solution

#### 1. Try disconnect socket first when you call `navigate` as below.

```
navigate() {
    this.socket.disconnect();
    this.props.navigation.navigate('CoinCapCharts');
}
```

#### 2. Use navigation lifecycle listener: [doc](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html#addlistener-subscribe-to-updates-to-navigation-lifecycle)

- willFocus - the screen will focus
- willBlur - the screen will be unfocused
- didFocus - the screen focused (if there was a transition, the transition completed)
- didBlur - the screen unfocused (if there was a transition, the transition completed)

---

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.didFocusSubscription = this.props.navigation.addListener(
    'willFocus', () => { DO_WHAT_YOU_WANT }
  );
}

componentWillUnmout() {
    this.didFocusSubscription.remove();
}
```

## Why?

Your Screen Component's ummount is not guaranteed when you navigate screen especially while use `StackNavigation`. Because `StackNavigation` use push and pop for screen's stack and previous screen is not unmounted when another screen is pushed.

Comment: Precisely, I am thinking about moving to Tab's navigation because even if I am able to disconnect, I will have tough time turning socket.on when the user again gets back to the screen. 

Tab View should do the trick?

Comment: @VarunBindal I updated my answer. Using navigation lifecycle listener could be your solution.